# Installing nodejs binary files

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes

I have already installed nodejs and npm using yum but I don't understand why should I have to download and install nodejs binary files? These are the files provided by the official site [node js site](https://nodejs.org/en/). How can one check the version of the binary file(s)?

Comment: You shouldn't need to download and installing them again [after installing with yum](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora). Why do you believe you do need to? – For your other question, you should be able to run `node --version` from a shell/terminal to see the installed version.

Comment: thanks... for clarifying the doubt